# Regular or normal topological space

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

**How do we define an open neighborhood around a closed set?** My question is with respect to a normal or regular topological space where  we use the concept of an open neighborhood around a closed set.

Comment: An open set containing $A$ (let's call the set $A$).

Comment: Some people just define it as an open set $O$ such that $O\supseteq F$, where $F$ is your closed set.

Answer (score 1):

Just like an open neighbourhood of $x$ is an open set that contains $x$, an open neighbourhood of a closed set $F$ is just an open set that contains it: $F \subseteq O$.

This is essentially the same as what @Lefschetz is saying in the other post: if we have $O$ we could pick $O$ for every point of $F$ as well, and if we pick an open neighbourhood for every point, their union is exactly an open superset of $F$.

Comment: Yeah. I also constructed the open set in the same fashion. But I am not able to prove that for a closed set $F$, $ F \subset  \cup U(x)$ (always) where $U(x)$ is an open neighborhood around $x, \; \forall x \in F$.

Comment: @RichardJ This is true by construction: if for each $x \in F$ we pick some $U(x)$ open and containing $x$, then this $x$ is certainly in the union $\cup_{x \in F} U(x)$, and this holds for all $x \in F$, so $F \subset \cup_{x \in F} U(x)$. And this union is clearly open.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough points to comment; if someone could please turn this into a comment: maybe you can do this for each point x in the closed set C , take an open set $U_x$ containing x. Then $\cup U_x$ for all $x$ in $C$ is an open neighborhood containing $C$. For spaces like manifolds, you have , under the right conditions, regular neighborhoods or tubular neighborhoods.

Comment: is it necessary that $C \subset \cup U_x $?? what if $\cup U_x$ lies completely within $C$?